# conditional redirect from a button

Tags: apex, force.com

I'm trying to redirect the user to a page from a button on a related list on a standard pageLayout. if it's initiated from a contact i want it to go to A, and from an account, i want it to go to B. I have the idea of it, but my syntax is off.

```
if( 
(CONTAINS($currentPage.URL, "/003")
, 
{!URLFOR($Action.Task.NewTask, null, [retURL=URLFOR($Action.Contact.View,Contact.Id),save_new_url="/apex/mytask?whoId=" +Contact.Id+"&ownerId="+ $User.Id  ])}
,
{!URLFOR($Action.Task.NewTask, null, [retURL=URLFOR($Action.Account.View,Account.Id),save_new_url="/apex/myask?whatId=" +Account.Id+"&ownerId="+ $User.Id  ])}      
)
```

Comment: You can probably figure this out, but personally I've always just created multiple buttons, one for each parent object the related list appears on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things for custom buttons:

1. Wrap everything that's going to get merged with `{}`
2. No such variable as $CurrentPage for buttons, (but I have a workaround)
3. Make sure your all your parens and braces balance out (guessing that's a typo in the question)

Taken into account the above this might be what you're looking for

```
{!IF(
  ISBLANK(Contact.Id)
, URLFOR(
    $Action.Task.NewTask
  , null
  , [retURL=URLFOR($Action.Contact.View,Contact.Id)
    ,save_new_url="/apex/mytask?whoId=" +Contact.Id+"&ownerId="+ $User.Id  ])
, URLFOR(
    $Action.Task.NewTask
  , null
  , [retURL=URLFOR($Action.Account.View,Account.Id)
    , save_new_url="/apex/myask?whatId=" +Account.Id+"&ownerId="+ $User.Id  ])
)}
```

That said, a simpler approach would just be to create one button for each of the potential sources.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the way we can redirect new button conditionally.
[How to conditionally redirect newbutton override Visualforce page](http://www.exampeta.com/article/agpzfmV4YW1wZXRhchULEghBcnRpY2xlcxiAgICgtaa0CQw/How-to-conditionally-redirect-newbutton-override--Visualforce-page-)